# What is the value of knowing the eigenfunctions of an operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $f_i$ be the set of functions of operator $O$ such that $Of_i = \lambda_if_i\;\;\lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}$

In linear algebra, there are a number of uses of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Are there similar theorems for eigenfunctions?

For example the eigenfunctions of $\frac{d}{dx}$ are $e^{\lambda x}\;\;\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$

So we know that these eigenfunctions are part of the solution space for LODEs. But so are $xe^{\lambda x}$ which don't seem to be eigenfunctions.

Ay insights would be helpful! Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory

Answer (score 1):

If you want to solve
$$
         \left(\frac{d}{dx}-\lambda\right)^nf=0
$$
then you can rewrite this as
$$
        \left(e^{\lambda x}\frac{d}{dx}e^{-\lambda x}\right)^nf= e^{\lambda x}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(e^{-\lambda x}f)=0,
$$
which leads to solutions
\begin{align}
          e^{-\lambda x}f &= a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1 x + a_0 \\
          f&=(a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots + a_1 x + a_0)e^{\lambda x}.
\end{align}